# jquery autocomplete: this.menu undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery UI Autocomplete for some data. Now I have 3 autocomplete elements and 2 of these work fine, one doesn't. At the start of the page he gives me the error `elem.ownerDocument is null`. When I put text into the `input` field he find result but I get the error `this.menu is undefined (jquery.js line 6012)` which refers to the `ul list` where the result should be shown.

Here some code:

```
$("#iName").autocomplete({
    source: widget.festivals_list,
    autofocus: true,
    focus: function (e, ui) {
        return false;
    },
    search: function (event, ui){
        ownFest = true;
        $("#iDate").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#iTime").removeAttr("disabled");
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        ownFest = false;
        $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
        selectedN = ui.item.value;
        $(widget.festivals).each(function fn(){
            if(this.id == ui.item.value){
                $("#iDate").val(this.date).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#iTime").val(this.time).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Type the name</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="iFest"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

This creates the typical number of attributes on my `input` tag and creates the `ul` list.

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem"></ul>

<input id="iFest" class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
```

Someone who also had these problems?
Thanks

(Using jQuery 1.5.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.11)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because your 'this' is out of scope.

Inside a function, 'this' isn't always what you think it is.

usual solution is to make a reference to your global 'this'

```
var element = $(this);
```

or

```
var me = this;
```

And refer to element instead of 'this' when you're in a function.

Can you post your HTML too ? or indicate which line has the error ? I can't seem to see it from your snippet.

Comment: Changed the content of my question

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a library referenced by autocomplete.

So, include this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js"></script>
```

Good luck!